# Identify the value with highest number of decimal values

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, max, decimal, rounding

I have a range of values and I want to count the decimal points of all values in the range and display the max count. the formula should exclude the zeroes at the end(not count ending zeroes in the decimal points).

[image]

for example, in the above sample, in the whole range the max of count of decimal places is 4 excluding the ending zeroes. so the answer is 4 to be displayed in cell `D2`

I tried doing regex, but do not know how do I do it for a whole range of values.

Please help!

Comment: Show us a formula, on E2 .. G4, that displays number of decimal places, e.g. {3, 2, 4} on 1st column. Displaying them individually will make it easy to debug / verify. Then compute MAX( ... ) over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(MAX(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A2:C4), "(\..+)")*1))-2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @player0. Can you please help explain why the *1 and -2 and the end?

Comment: I got it, so the ```REGEXEXTRACT``` extracts the decimal point and the numbers after it, then the ```IFERROR``` is for error handling, ```LEN``` finds the length of that string and ```MAX``` will make find the maximum and subtract 2 to not count the decimal point and the ending zero

Comment: @AliciaStone almost correct. we extract everything after decimal including the decimal. then we multiply it by one to convert it to number which will add zero before decimal point and remove all redundant zeros within decimal places. then we read the length and subtract 2 as a correction which stands for leading zero and decimal.

Comment: Thank you, when there are no decimal places, the result is ```-1```, how can we tweak to get 0 when a whole number is entered

Comment: @AliciaStone try: `=INDEX(MAX(0, LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A2:C4), "(\..+)")*1))-2))`

Answer (score 0):

[Player0's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932216/6770384) is a good start, but uses `TO_TEXT` which seems to rely on the formatting of your cells.
If you want to safely compute the number of decimal places, use the `TEXT` function instead.

[image: Screenshot: Google sheet comparing TO_TEXT and TEXT function for different cell formats]

`TEXT(number, format)` requires a format whose max. number of decimal places has to be specified. There is no way around this, because formulas like `=1/3` can have infinitely many decimal places.
Therefore, first decide on the max, precision for your use-case (here we use 8). Then use below function which works independently from your document's formatting and language:

```
=INDEX(MAX(
  LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(
    TEXT(ABS(A2:C4); "."&REPT("#";8));
    "[,.].*$"
  ))-1
))
```

We subtract `-1` since `LEN(REGEXEXTRACT())` also counts the decimal separator (`.` for english, [`,` for many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg)) .

Everything after the 8th decimal place is ignored. If all your numbers are something like `123.00000000987` the computed max. is 0. If you prefer it to be 8 instead, then add `ROUNDUP(   ; 8)`:

```
=INDEX(MAX(
  LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(
    TEXT(ROUNDUP(ABS(A2:C4);8); "."&REPT("#";8));
    "[,.].*$"
  ))-1
))
```